# How to check if URL is valid

Tags: url, cmd, ping

Trying to make a list of valid symbols unable to locate on world wide web. I'm trying to loop through 1 million URL's since there is no logical codification to the assigned values.

I am trying to use `PING` return values to validate them, but the question is: is this possible?

problem is:

> PING finance.yahoo.com **works**

but:

> PING finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=*601588*.SS+Historical+Prices **doesn't work**

(tried to loop second address with var italicized)

Comment: Oops ! What environment?

Comment: Windows/DOS @sjsam

Comment: The answer below already satisfies your requirement provided you have curl pre-installed. I think it is available with Powershell..

Answer (score 3):

If possible use curl instead

```
curl -I http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=601588.SS+Historical+Prices
```